# Install oracle java jdk 12

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I installed Oracle Java Jdk 12 from here:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html

But the installation explanation is cryptic to me:

> Unpack the tarball and install the JDK: $ tar zxvf
>   jdk-12.interim.update.patch_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
>
> The Java Development Kit files are installed in a directory called
>   jdk-12.interim.update.patch.

But it doesn't tell what command to use to install it.

Comment: You didn't get jdk 12... you got a patch for jdk 12. Oracle Java license has changed. You may wish to install OpenJDK instead.

Comment: @heynnema that means i have to pay for the oracle jdk? Unfortunately i was working with a program synthesis tool and open jdk doesnt work....

Comment: I don't know. Read the new licensing info at the web link you gave. It says it's ok for personal use only.

Comment: @heynnema is for personal use that i want it. is just i don't see what the installation command is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html) to get to the download page.

Note the new licensing agreement...

[image]

Go to the bottom of the page, find the area shown below, accept the license agreement, click the download link...

[image]

Once downloaded, double-click on the .deb file to install it.

Comment: I donwloaded the tar.gz, then added the bin file to the path, this was the way it worked for me

Comment: @Javier I'm glad it's working for you, but those were not my instructions. I suggested using the .deb file. You can still do that, and remove your path changes.