# How to install tar.gz files in Kubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, kubuntu

So I have been trying to install an older version of Java for an application and I don't know how to install tar.gz files, so I googled it and tried the

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

but it didn't work. There is no install.txt or other types of instructions cause Oracle. What are some alternate solutions?

Comment: what version of java and where did you get the file?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen jre1.7.0_80 from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148610/install-oracle-java-jdk-12/1148851#1148851

Comment: @heynnema runtime not jdk

Comment: @bobasrty The JDK includes the JRE, so you do not have to download both separately... and it comes in a nice .deb installer.

Comment: @heynnema ok thx